# Get mongo autocompletion options in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongo-shell

In a MongoDB shell when I hit the tab key twice you get all the available options for autocompletion. Is there a way to get these options inside NodeJS?

Comment: You mean inside your IDE?

Comment: No, I want to create a simple mongodb manager app. There should be an option to run custom commands, like `db.getCollection('somthing').find()` and when users starts typing `db.getColl` I want to show autocomplete options and offer `db.getCollection`

Comment: Erm you mean something like an shell? Which can be used remotely? And provides authentication? With all schemes provided by mongoDB? Well, you might want to have a look [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/shell). Suggestion: do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I just want to get the output of double clicking the tab key in mongo into nodejs. Is that possible?